# Thymeleaf th:onclick event - calling confirm function

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf. Recently I stumbled in the following situation. Here is a piece of my Thymeleaf html page:

```
<!-- an delete button link -->
<a th:href="@{/employees/delete(employeeId=${tempEmployee.emplId},firstName=${tempEmployee.firstName},lastName=${tempEmployee.lastName})}"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm py-1 "
    th:onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this employee ?') )) return false" >
    Delete
</a>
```

This code works fine as intended. However I want to add employee name as part of the confirmation. Here is the code:

```
<!-- an delete button link -->
<a th:href="@{/employees/delete(employeeId=${tempEmployee.emplId},firstName=${tempEmployee.firstName},lastName=${tempEmployee.lastName})}"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm py-1 "
    th:onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this employee ' + '\'+${tempEmployee.firstName}+\'' +'?' ) )) return false" >
    Delete
</a>
```

Unfortunately the result is:
`Are you sure you want to delete this employee 
 '+${tempEmployee.firstName}+'`.

Looks like Thymeleaf does not recognize ${tempEmployee.firstName}. It has no problem with it in th:href tag but does not like it in th:onclick.

I would appreciate if somebody can turn me into the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the problem is (though it may be related to `onclick` vs `th:onclick`.  Regardless, I think a format more like this will work (with some added benefits like no JavaScript injection).

```
<!-- an delete button link -->
<a
  th:href="@{/employees/delete(employeeId=${tempEmployee.emplId},firstName=${tempEmployee.firstName},lastName=${tempEmployee.lastName})}"
  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm py-1 "
  th:data-confirm-delete="|Are you sure you want to delete this employee ${tempEmployee.firstName}?|"
  onclick="if (!confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm-delete'))) return false"
>
  Delete
</a>
```

(Notice I'm using `onclick` and not `th:onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  this line in above code `---onclick="if (!confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm-delete'))) return false">`

You can write as:
`onclick="return confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm-delete'))"`